# How to reliably redefine scroll wheel in isearch? [I'm using Mitsuharu Yamamoto's Mac port]

Tags: key-bindings, osx, keymap, mouse

I decided to define `<wheel-up>` and `<wheel-down>` to `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward` in the `isearch-mode-map`.

This works, but if you scroll quickly, it reverts to ordinary scrolling behavior and cancels your isearch. It helped a lot to define `<double-wheel-up>` etc, but if you scroll very quickly, the problem still occurs.

How can I redefine scroll events independent of scrolling speed?